# Can't run Minecraft with Ubuntu or Wine since update to 14.04

Tags: java, minecraft

I have followed other available advice on Minecraft, Java, etc, but can't find anything that works. Here is my story:

For a couple years I have been successfully running a cracked Windows version of Minecraft with Wine, it worked perfectly. After having problems updating to 14.04 and deciding to do a fresh install, I never bothered to reinstall Minecraft. Recently, I decided to pay for a legit version of Minecraft and found that there is now a Linux version, so I created an account and downloaded the files.

However, attempts to install this version were initially met with glx errors, and after following some fixes the new error is that Minecraft requires a kernel of 3.6 or above. `uname -r` shows my kernel is 3.4, and all attempts to upgrade to a newer kernel have failed, or more accurately, not had any effect. Frustrated, I attempted to install the Minecraft .exe in wine the way I used to run it, but each time I am informed that my java is not up to date (application requires a java runtime environment 1.6.0), any attempt to update fails with the following error message:

> "Installation failed, the wizard was interrupted before java 7 update 67 could be completely installed. To complete installation at another time, please run setup again."

Following any fixes I could find broke so many things on my machine that I ended up doing a powerwash and starting all over again with a fresh install, but I can still not successfully upgrade my kernel or make Minecraft work in wine.

To summarize, I have two basic questions:

1. Why can't I upgrade my kernel?
2. Why can't I install Minecraft in Wine as I used to have it?

Running Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE on Acer c720 chromebook.

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.4.0 #1 SMP Thu Jul 24 15:16:00 PDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit:  more info

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk-amd64   java-7-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk-common

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode
```

Comment: A clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 comes wih linux kernel 3.13, are you sure this is a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: yes, this has been tried multiple times, and i am still showing a kernel 3.4 and unable to upgrade.

Comment: in chrome shell, i entered:  sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t xfce -e

Comment: Crouton uses the kernel from Chrome OS.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions from this YouTube Video: [How to get Minecraft on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSEWrm9djGA)

To update Java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To install Minecraft:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

But the kernel issue is still a mystery.